# How to redirect tracepoint output to a file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, debugging, logging, methods, tracepoint

I am using the TracePoint class to trace a specific method in a large project, however, I need to also interact with the console the project provides. Although interaction works. I need to see any prompts the console makes, which is not possible due to the output of the tracepoint (there are A LOT of method calls).

Therefore, I would like to redirect the output of the Tracepoint to another file (for example another terminal's tty but not necessarily).

Is there a way to achieve this?

As an example, I have the following:
I would like to keep all outputs normal, except for the ones done by Tracepoint.

```
def start_trace
    trace =
    TracePoint.new(:call) { |tp| p [tp.path, tp.lineno, tp.event, tp.method_id] }
    trace.enable
    yield
    trace.disable
  end


def fun1
    puts("This is fun1")
end

def fun2
    puts("This is fun2")
end

def fun3(num)
    puts("This is fun3: " + num)
    fun2
end

start_trace { fun3("bye") }
```

Comment: In your code, you are using `p`, which writes to stdout. Just use here a different method, if you want to write the output to a different stream.

Comment: @user1934428 where do I find info on what redirection is available? Or how do I redirect it to a specific file?

Comment: I would pass an object of type `File` to your class which uses the Trace. Let's call this variable `@destination`. Then, instead of doing simply a `p`, you are doing a `@destination.p(....)`, respectively `@destination.puts(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a comment said, the `p` prints to stdout. To redirect the output to another TTY (or another file), the file needs to be opened and the `.print` method can be used. The following code gets the desired functionality:

```
def start_trace
    file = File.open("/dev/ttys007", "w")
    trace =
    TracePoint.new(:call) { |tp| 
        file.print [tp.path, tp.lineno, tp.event, tp.method_id]
        file.puts()
    }
    trace.enable
    yield
    trace.disable
    file.close
  end


def fun1
    puts("This is fun1")
end

def fun2
    puts("This is fun2")
end

def fun3(num)
    puts("This is fun3: " + num)
    fun2
end

start_trace { fun3("bye") }
```